# Android library activity should open independently with its own theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-library

I want to create my own library, which contains common functionality flow. So that it can used in multiple apps at runtime, by just importing my library.

I am following [Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) and some [examples](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library) to create library.

I am defining theme for my library is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Application using my library having defined theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

So my problem is: when user call action to open my library, library should open without action bar, but it open below the Application action bar/toolbar.

I am adding image, which will describe my actual problem:

[image]

Is there any setting which will help me to open my library with my defined theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below the onCreate.

```
 getSupportActionBar().hide()
```

In styles.xml similar to this:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

> **Note:-** Need to add below condition, in case of library. Because some application might already have ***NoActionBar theme***.

```
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
```

Comment: please, use english

Comment: @MarcosApps, Thanks it works fine and accept edit request.